# How to change range of cells in a series of lists? (Pandas reading from Excel)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am working with Pandas, Excel and Matplotlib.
The program performs some operations on the data stored in Excel and saved them there as well.
Next, it plots the data.
The data to be plotted consists of way too many arrays that go like follows:

```
x=list(excelfile['Дата'][2:3625])
y1=list(excelfile['a'][2:3625])
y2=list(excelfile['a1'][2:3625])
y3=list(excelfile['a1=f(b)'][2:3625])
y4=list(excelfile['c'][2:3625])
y5=list(excelfile['c=f(d)'][2:3625])
```

Is there any way I could set the range of cells ([2:3625]) manually, once and for all, without having to rewrite it every time I want to work with a different range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you find yourself doing repetitive work, you need variables and functions. For example

```py
def getData(filename, startCell, endCell):
    return list(excelfile[filename][startCell:endCell]


startCell = 2
endCell = 3625

x = getData('Дата', startCell, endCell)
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the range values to variables, like in the code below.

```py
a = 2
b = 3625
x=list(excelfile['Дата'][a:b])
y1=list(excelfile['a'][a:b])
y2=list(excelfile['a1'][a:b])
y3=list(excelfile['a1=f(b)'][a:b])
y4=list(excelfile['c'][a:b])
y5=list(excelfile['c=f(d)'][a:b])
```